# History of measure theory

Tags: mathematics

Is there a book anybody here can recommend on the history of measure theory? Or, maybe a book that contains the history of measure theory?

Most books that are supposed to cover this material, i.e. books on the integration theory that lead to the measure theory, explain the integration quite well, but barely mention the measure theory.

The reason I want to learn the history of measure theory is to better understand the theory itself. So, I want a book that goes beyond just the history of measure theory, and also delves into the mathematics of the theory. The things I am most interested in are the definitions, like $\sigma$-algebra, and measurability, and the rationale and the evolution of these concepts.

Comment: [Did you even bother to google? This is my first result (took me about 5 seconds...)](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~marcus/Math507420/Math507420hist.pdf)

Comment: And [I found this source about 15 seconds later](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=CHEL-282-H)

Comment: Related [math.se] post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036295/development-of-measure-theory

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of lack of research effort.

Comment: I know about that pdf. However, did you read my second paragraph? That pdf does not go through any of the mathematics. I did not know about the book. So, I'll skim through it.

Comment: I found the book in the library, and looking through it, it barely mentions measure theory. For instance, concepts like $\sigma$-algebra and countable additivity are not even in the index. Its main focus is integration, and it does not really care about the measure theory. Carathéodory is only mentioned on one page (in a footnote about Cantor).

And, that is why I asked the question. Google does not really tell you the contents of a book.The book you found is probably good if you care about the integration theory, but not measure theory. My post does not even mention integration.

Comment: @Avatrin Please edit your question to reflect that you *did* do some prior research, and make it very clear what exactly is not satisfactory about the easily-found sources. Basically, rewrite the stuff you wrote in the comments in the main text! This would improve the question greatly.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll do that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of lack of research effort.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is such a book. 
MR0264015 Pesin, Ivan N. Classical and modern integration theories. Translated from the Russian and edited by Samuel Kotz. Probability and Mathematical Statistics, No. 8 Academic Press, New York-London 1970 xviii+195 pp.

The original Russian title, literally translated is: "Develpment of the notion of Integral". I read the book, and can recommend it.

Comment: Yes, great book, I also enjoyed it: the Russian 1966 print BTW is on publ.lib.ru/ARCHIVES/P/PESIN_Ivan_Nikolaevich/_Pesin_I.N..html for anybody who wants to read that

Answer (score 4):

The book *Lebesgue's theory of integration: Its origins and development* by T. Hawkins.